# Is slow growth a virulence factor?

Tags: immunology, infection, infectious-diseases

Many slow-growth pathogens (e.g. Mycobacterium tuberculosis, lentivirus, Rhabdovirus, Leptospira spp) are difficult to treat. In addition, a [review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5352820/) of 61 pathogens found that

> slower growing pathogens are significantly more virulent than faster growing pathogens

I was wondering why this may be the case. Is slow growth a virulence factor? How does slow growth benefit a pathogen?